# Como ler arquivos de textos grandes no Android?

Tags: android, arquivo, firebase

Queria saber alguma dica sobre como ler arquivos grandes no Android, como exemplo dou os arquivos de GTFS (Google Transit) que na maioria das vezes tem 80 MB

Estou colocando estes dados em um servidor (Firebase) com utilização de aplicativo Android utilitário.

Porém estou recebendo erros quando a leitura esta pela metade,ou seja, quando o aplicativo estoura a memória.

Observação: este método que uso.

```js
public List<String> readFile(String fileName){

        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(fileName)));
            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            if((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                //text.add(mLine);
                Log.i(TAG, "          head " + mLine);
            }
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.add(mLine);
                Log.i(TAG, "          line " + mLine);
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"sucess "+fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "error " + fileName);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```